# wc -c and wc -m give the same output all the time?

Tags: linux, wc

I am having the following doubt. wc -m and wc -c are always giving same output. I tried with floating point numbers also but the output is same for both the commands.

```
 cat test | wc -m
 541
 cat test | wc -c
 541
```

Comment: It makes sense for these two to be equal, as char and byte data types both take one byte in most cases. wc -c (the number of bytes) and wc -m (the number of chars) should be the same.

Answer (score 4):

ASCII character takes byte. But UTF-8 local charaters takes 2 bytes.

```
 echo -n "ŻÓŹŁŃĘ"|wc -m
 6
 echo -n "ŻÓŹŁŃĘ"|wc -c
 12
```

P.S. You can `wc -m test` to save cat.